# calculus 2: Find the volume of the solid

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

> Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded
>   by the given curves about the specified line. Sketch the region, the
>   solid, and a typical disk or washer.

$$y = 1 + sec\;x,\;y =3,\;about\;y=1$$

How is the inner-radius of the cross-section $sec\;x$? Why isn't it $1 + sec\;x?$

Comment: Because you're revolving about the line $y=1$.

Comment: Will you please elaborate?

Comment: Did you do the sketching step?  That may help.  Also I am assuming you are only looking at one branch of the secant function, although that is not clear from the problem's statement.

Comment: Yes,I have the correct graph in front of me. Every problem I've done up to now the inner-radius has just been the curve. You said it was because it's revolving around y=1, does that mean if it revolved around y=2 the inner-radius would be [(1 + secx) -2]?

Answer (score 1):

Draw a rectangle representing the direction the function will rotate around the given line/axis.

Its easy to see that the rectangle formed will have the width $\delta x$ and height $y+1 - 1 = (\sec x + 1)- 1 = \sec x$